# How to make the connection string visible throughout the solution (across layers)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

I have developed an Asp.net application using three tire architecture and i am reading the connetions string from web.conf file in the UI layer,

My problem is i have to pass the connection string as a parameter in all the functions that are in the Bo layer.

Is there any work around for making the connection string visible throughout the Bo layer so that i dont need to send the connetions string as parameter in all my method calls.

Answer (score 4):

Include the **System.Configuration** reference to all projects in which you want to access the connection string and use the following code to access your connection string.

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["MyConnection"].ConnectionString
```

It is advisable to use a helper class to access your connection string.

```
internal sealed class Utility
{
     public static string MyConnectionString{
          get{
               return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
          }
     }
}
```

This will help you to move your connection string from web.config to any other location in future without breaking your code.

Comment: but will this be visible throughout this proj

Comment: You can make the utility class public and can access it throughout the project.